# How zoom base on scale in OpenLayers 4?

Tags: javascript, scale, openlayers, dpi

I want to zoom to ol3 map base on scale(for example 1:50000). This means every 1cm in ol map must show 50000cm in real world. for converting scale to resolution I used as follows:

```
var getResolutionFromScale = function(scale, units) {
    var dpi = getDpi();
    var mpu = ol.proj.METERS_PER_UNIT[units];
    var inchesPerMeter = 39.37;
    return parseFloat(scale) / (mpu * inchesPerMeter * dpi);
}

function getDPI()
{
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.width="1in";
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    body.appendChild(div);
    var dpi = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(div, null).getPropertyValue('width');
    body.removeChild(div);
    return parseFloat(dpi);
}
```

Now for testing it, I use ScaleLine and when scaleLine controle show 1000m, it's length must be 2cm, but it is almost 2.5cm.

Where is th problem? How can I zoom base on scale?

**[Online Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rgpkuh0s/1)**

Answer (score 2):

The projection is a [Mercator projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) that preserve angles but not the distance. This means that the scale is not the same on the whole map :(

To see it, just move from equator to the pole and see the ScaleLine length growing.

Thus you just can't calculate the scale worldwide, you have to calculate it locally (calculate a distance between 2 points at the center of the view in the map projection and the [haversine distance](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Sphere.html#haversineDistance) to get the ratio). Be aware the DPI depends on the device (screen, printer) your are using and may be quite different form one to another.

You can use the `geometry.getLength()` and `ol.Sphere.getLength()` to compute the 2 distances.
Look at the ol example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure.html